# problems about socket set no_delay and keep alive

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I want to set socket's opts like no_delay and keep alive.

do i need call the function setsockopt in both server side and client side or just call this function in either server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

Both those options apply to sending. If you want both sides to use TCP_NODELAY and keepalive when sending, set it at both sides. In the case of keep-alive, it is sufficient to set it at one end only.

Answer (score 0):

sockets are required at both end server end and client end ..
if its server socket option set it in the server socket options ..same goes for client end..its like setting options for phone at the both ends for configuration.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He asked whether he *needs* to call these functions at both ends. The answer depends on what he wants.